# How to remove the inline styles from the content of a WYSIWYG editor field at the time of saving the post?

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I am using the WYSIWYG editor as a custom field using ACF plugin to insert a custom table in the field.

As a data, the table needed is simply the HTML Markup of it only, only attributes specific to table tag. but in the process, we all know the editor injects inline style to the , ,, etc tags which I don't need, as I will target the content using ID and Class only while styling. Hence I think it is better to remove them for good.
In this example the **field id(Meta Key): job_table**.
Some please suggest how to strip certain attributes, while saving the post.